# Angular Mat-Table-Header doesn't stay sticky when adding class

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm having a problem styling a Mat-Table-Header. When adding sticky = true to the MatHeaderRowRef everything works fine, as soon as I add a class to one of the <th> of one column this header doesn't stay sticky and goes up and down while scrolling, the other ones stay sticky.

[image]

```
            <ng-container matColumnDef="time">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="header-align-left"     (click)="sortDataSource()">{{'SHARED.TIME_UC' |
                translate}}</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.time }}</td>
            </ng-container>
```

```
  .header-align-left{
    display: flex;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;    
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
```

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-container { 
    display: flex;  
    justify-content:flex-end; 
}
```

I already tried several possibilities, e.g adding an inline style, nothing works.

Comment: can you share stackblitz?